# Scrolling div is overflowing from position-fixed div

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing Chrome extension and I have a problem. Scrolling div is overflowing from position-fixed div. How can I solve this problem?

Scrolling divs are  `#fragment1` and `#fragment2`

Position-fixed div is `#main`

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
        <div id="header">
            <span id="header_text"></span>
        </div>

        <div id="fragment1" class="fragment">
            <h3 class="ch"><i class="fas fa-chart-line icon"></i> Döviz Takibi</h3>
            <input type="number" id="input_currency" min="0" placeholder="Döviz Miktarı (Döviz/TL)" autocomplete="off">
            
            <div id="div_currency" style="overflow: auto;white-space: nowrap;margin: auto;text-align: center;">
                <button id="btn_dollar"><i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i> Dolar</button>
                <button id="btn_euro"><i class="fas fa-euro-sign"></i> Euro</button>
                <button id="btn_pound"><i class="fas fa-pound-sign"></i> Sterlin</button>
            </div>
            <br>
            <h3 class="ch"><i class="fas fa-box-open"></i> Diğer</h3>
            <div id="div_other" style="overflow: auto;white-space: nowrap;margin: auto;text-align: center;">
                <button id="btn_weather"><i class="fas fa-temperature-high"></i> Tunceli Hava Durumu</button>
                <button id="btn_covid19"><i class="fas fa-virus"></i> Covid-19 Bilgi Paneli</button>
            </div>
            <br>
            <input type="number" id="input_timer" min="0" max="9999" placeholder="Zamanlayıcı Süresi (dk.)" autocomplete="off">
            <button style="width: 100%;" id="btn_timer"><i class="fas fa-stopwatch"></i> Zamanlayıcı</button>
        </div>

        <div id="fragment2" class="fragment">
            <h3 class="ch"><i class="fas fa-cog icon"></i> Ayarlar</h3>
            <b class="sh"><i style="color: var(--theme-color);" class="fas fa-fill-drip"></i> Tema Rengi</b>
            <br>
            <input id="input_theme_color" type="color">
            <br>
            <div id="history_scroll" class="scroll"></div>
            <div id="history">
                <button id="btn_show_history"><i style="float: left;" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>Geçmiş<i style="float: right;" class="fas fa-history"></i></button>
                <button id="btn_hide_history"><i style="float: left;transform: rotate(90deg);" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i><span id="btn_hide_history_text">Geçmiş</span><i style="float: right;" class="fas fa-history"></i></button>
                <div id="history_content"></div>
                <button id="btn_clear_history">Geçmişi Temizle <i class="fas fa-trash-restore"></i></button>
            </div>

            <div id="details">
                <button id="btn_show_details"><i style="float: left;" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>Detaylar<i style="float: right;" class="fas fa-info-circle"></i></button>
                <button id="btn_hide_details"><i style="float: left;transform: rotate(90deg);" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>Detaylar<i style="float: right;" class="fas fa-info-circle"></i></button>
                <div id="details_content">
                    <span id="settings_update_text"></span>
                    <div class="border"></div>
                    <span id="history_clear_text"></span>
                    <br>
                    <button id="btn_extension_page">Eklenti Sayfası <i class="fas fa-external-link-square-alt"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="details_scroll" class="scroll"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main{
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
    background-color: rgb(23, 23, 23,0.6);
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    height: 82%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 23px 0px var(--theme-color);
}

#header{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    background: var(--theme-color);
    color: var(--theme-txt-color);
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: var(--theme-border-radius);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 23px 0px black;
}

#header_text{font-size: 25px;font-weight: bold;}

.fragment{
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**Screen Shot**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can move `overflow-y: auto;` to the #main div.

If you want header fixed have a look at this:

```
#main {
  position: fixed;
  background: grey;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  height: 82%;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#header {
  height:10%;
  background: yellow;
}

#scroll {
  height:90%;
  overflow: auto;
}

<div id="main">
  <div id="header">header</div>
  <div id="scroll">
    scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>
    scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>
    scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>
    scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>
    scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>scroll<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JSFIDDLE**: https://jsfiddle.net/csrt1540/

Comment: I think problem is height: 100% for fragments. Because if this value is 80%, no problem. But I want to fill #main div with #fragment1(2) and #header.

Comment: I tried here: https://jsfiddle.net/07vjrk1f/
what do you need?

Comment: I want to see #header top of the #main everytime. So ı don't want this way. You can say "use position:absolute" but it is not working.

Comment: is this solution ok? https://jsfiddle.net/csrt1540/

Answer (score -1):

I do not know why you set the heaight of fragments to 100% (Is there some reason?). I think it is not necessary there, if you remove it and then listen to Davide (move overflow to main) it should works fine.
Regarding your reply: "I want to see #header top of the #main everytime. So ı don't want this way. You can say 'use position:absolute' but it is not working." - You can use 'position: sticky' on header, if you want it to be always on top. I can not reply to you in conversation with Davide, because i don't have enough reputation points.
There is an example with 'position: sticky':

```css
#main{
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
    background-color: rgb(23, 23, 23,0.6);
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    height: 82%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 23px 0px var(--theme-color);
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#header{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    background: var(--theme-color);
    color: var(--theme-txt-color);
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: var(--theme-border-radius);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 23px 0px black;
  position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

#header_text{font-size: 25px;font-weight: bold;}
```

```html
<div id="main">
        <div id="header">
            <span id="header_text"></span>
        </div>

        <div id="fragment1" class="fragment">
            <h3 class="ch"><i class="fas fa-chart-line icon"></i> Döviz Takibi</h3>
            <input type="number" id="input_currency" min="0" placeholder="Döviz Miktarı (Döviz/TL)" autocomplete="off">
            
            <div id="div_currency" style="overflow: auto;white-space: nowrap;margin: auto;text-align: center;">
                <button id="btn_dollar"><i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i> Dolar</button>
                <button id="btn_euro"><i class="fas fa-euro-sign"></i> Euro</button>
                <button id="btn_pound"><i class="fas fa-pound-sign"></i> Sterlin</button>
            </div>
            <br>
            <h3 class="ch"><i class="fas fa-box-open"></i> Diğer</h3>
            <div id="div_other" style="overflow: auto;white-space: nowrap;margin: auto;text-align: center;">
                <button id="btn_weather"><i class="fas fa-temperature-high"></i> Tunceli Hava Durumu</button>
                <button id="btn_covid19"><i class="fas fa-virus"></i> Covid-19 Bilgi Paneli</button>
            </div>
            <br>
            <input type="number" id="input_timer" min="0" max="9999" placeholder="Zamanlayıcı Süresi (dk.)" autocomplete="off">
            <button style="width: 100%;" id="btn_timer"><i class="fas fa-stopwatch"></i> Zamanlayıcı</button>
        </div>

        <div id="fragment2" class="fragment">
            <h3 class="ch"><i class="fas fa-cog icon"></i> Ayarlar</h3>
            <b class="sh"><i style="color: var(--theme-color);" class="fas fa-fill-drip"></i> Tema Rengi</b>
            <br>
            <input id="input_theme_color" type="color">
            <br>
            <div id="history_scroll" class="scroll"></div>
            <div id="history">
                <button id="btn_show_history"><i style="float: left;" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>Geçmiş<i style="float: right;" class="fas fa-history"></i></button>
                <button id="btn_hide_history"><i style="float: left;transform: rotate(90deg);" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i><span id="btn_hide_history_text">Geçmiş</span><i style="float: right;" class="fas fa-history"></i></button>
                <div id="history_content"></div>
                <button id="btn_clear_history">Geçmişi Temizle <i class="fas fa-trash-restore"></i></button>
            </div>

            <div id="details">
                <button id="btn_show_details"><i style="float: left;" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>Detaylar<i style="float: right;" class="fas fa-info-circle"></i></button>
                <button id="btn_hide_details"><i style="float: left;transform: rotate(90deg);" class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>Detaylar<i style="float: right;" class="fas fa-info-circle"></i></button>
                <div id="details_content">
                    <span id="settings_update_text"></span>
                    <div class="border"></div>
                    <span id="history_clear_text"></span>
                    <br>
                    <button id="btn_extension_page">Eklenti Sayfası <i class="fas fa-external-link-square-alt"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="details_scroll" class="scroll"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I want to fill the #main div fragment1 or fragment2. So I did this .

Comment: I must use height because I want to scrolling feature.

Comment: You can use 'position: sticky' on header, if you want it to be always on top. There is an example: https://jsbin.com/jowumesomo/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).